# Display colors using cat command

Tags: linux, bash, colors

I try to create a log file in Bash. I want to have colored text (green for good news, yellow for warning etc.) I am using console codes. When I execute in the terminal the command:

```
echo -e "\033[1;31m Some text here \033[0m"
```

I have a good output. My text is colored. The problems start when I want to put such a line in the file. I put a line: `\033[1;31m Some text here \033[0m` into a file. Then I opened this file using `cat` command. The output is:

```
\033[1;31m Some text here \033[0m
```

This is exactly the same line that I entered into the file. Colors are not displayed. Is it possible to display colored text (console-codes) with the command cat? What I am doing wrong?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is it possible to display colored text (console-codes) with the command cat?

Sure. Even with `echo -e "\033[1;31m Some text here \033[0m" | cat`.

> What I am doing wrong?

You are expecting `cat` to replace `\033` (4 characters `\` `0` `3` `3`) to be replaced by **one** byte 0x1b. `cat` is not `tr`, it doesn't do translation. If you want cat to output something output the same thing in your file. Instead of inputting `\033` (4 characters) into your file, open the file in a hex editor and set the *byte* to 0x1b (or by other means... just `echo -e "\033[1;31m Some text here \033[0m" > file`...).

And, it's not a properly of `echo` nor `cat` to display colored text. It's your terminal that translates the characters into color - `echo` and `cat` only output bytes.

Comment: The key thing is that the file needs to contain a literal escape character for this to work.

Comment: @joanis - which is exactly what Kamil's `echo -e "\033[1;31m Some text here \033[0m" > fil` would do ... or am I misinterpreting your comment?

Comment: Indeed, that's what it does, but I didn't feel it was explained clearly enough, sorry for being misleading about that.